# How do you append created var elements inside one another in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

So I have some vars creating elements:

```
var dest = $("<div/>", {
  className: "something"});
var desul = $("<ul/>", {
  className: "list"});
var desLi = $("<li/>", {
  className: "list-item"}); 
var desa = $("<a/>", {
  href: "",
  className: "some-link",
  content: "Some Link"});
```

Now I do an append:

```
$("#target").append(???);
```

And what I want in the end is:

```
<div id="target">
  <div class="something">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">
        <a href="" class="some-link">Some Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how do I write the jQuery for the #target.append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below without separating it out in variables (unless you need to):

```
$("#target").append(
    $("<div/>", {className: "something"}).append(
    $("<ul/>", {className: "list"}).append(
    $("<li/>", {className: "list-item"}).append(
    $("<a/>", {href: "", className: "some-link",content: "Some Link"})))));
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't know this was possible. It reminds me of python for some reason.

Comment: Yeah this makes since. I've been trying to do something like $("#target").append(var1, [var2-child, var3-child2], var4...and of course, that wasn't working.

Comment: Yes, and the point of importance here is that you do `.append()` etc. on jQuery objects that are not yet in the DOM.

Comment: End result should be: <div#target><div.something><a>First Link</a></div><div.something><a>Second Link</a></div></div>

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#target").append(dest.append(desul.append(desLi.append(desa))));
```